# Group By with Ordering

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

im looking for a little help with an SQL query, I've been racking my brains for a few hours.

I have some data within an MSSQL table that looks like the following:

```
price, date
15.98, 2014-05-31 13:24:05.287
15.98, 2014-06-01 01:24:15.250
15.98, 2014-06-01 13:24:19.280
15.98, 2014-06-02 01:25:01.680
15.98, 2014-06-02 13:25:10.477
9.99, 2014-06-03 01:25:12.580
15.98   2014-06-03 13:26:01.930
15.98   2014-06-04 01:26:11.423
9.99    2014-06-04 13:26:17.853
9.99    2014-06-05 01:27:01.800
```

I would like to return the count of each price, however not grouping all prices together, I would like to group based on time too. The result I would like to return is:

```
price, count
15.98, 5
9.99, 1
15.98, 2
9.99, 2
```

How would I go about manipulating the GROUP BY clause to produce the above set?

Comment: can't you just use a subquery? like: `select a,c from (select a, b, count(a) as c from yourtable) order by b`

Answer (score 1):

This (grouping of continuous ranges) is called gaps-and-islands problem and can be effectively solved by using analytic functions (specifically `ROW_NUMBER()`)

```
SELECT price, COUNT(*) count
  FROM
(
  SELECT price, date, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rnum,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY price ORDER BY date) rnum2
    FROM table1 
) q
 GROUP BY price, rnum - rnum2
 ORDER BY MIN(rnum)
```

Output:

```
| PRICE | COUNT |
|-------|-------|
| 15.98 |     5 |
|  9.99 |     1 |
| 15.98 |     2 |
|  9.99 |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb62a/13)** demo

Comment: You may not have but I certainly did.

Comment: peterm, many thanks for your quick response. Do you have the MSSQL example by any chance? No worries if not, at least I know what solution i'm looking for now.

Comment: @Zane Fair enough. It's too late here. Didn't pay attention what RDMBS was mentioned. Answer is updated for SQL Server.

Comment: @user2008865 Updated for SQL Server

Comment: @user2008865 You're quite welcome. If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.